# Get BaseDirectory of an application from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have a winform application ABC. I'm installing this on my client devices using clickonce. In it's BaseDirectory (which is AppData\Local\Apps\xx\yy\zz\ for my application). In the zz folder I have a zip folder which I need to access from a windows service. Is there any way I can get the AppData location from my win service? Is it even possible? I had the assumption it's not possible since it means a third party can affect the application.

Comment: Once you have verified the service can access the path by hardcoding it, have he application write the path into the registry whenever it starts?

Comment: @AlexK.+1 for the registry idea. Right now I am writing the path to a text file as a workaround. I still want to know if there's a way I can get the app data location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option seems to be what [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069972/get-basedirectory-of-an-application-from-a-windows-service#comment73223414_43069972) suggested in the comments, save it in the registry upon installation and retrieve it with your service.

Another option might be using MSI and there's a C# wrapper for it on [GitHub](https://github.com/alialavia/MSINet).

An example:

```
// Look for installed products containing 'Word' in their name and show their installed location
foreach (var p in InstalledProduct.Enumerate())
{
    try
    {
        if (p.InstalledProductName.Contains("Word"))                     
            Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} is intalled in {1}", p.GUID, p.InstallLocation);                    
    }
    catch (MSIException ex)
    {
        // Some products might throw an exception trying to access InstalledProductName propoerty.
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty cool. I'm trying to understand what's going on in there to see if I can implement that in my code without introducing a whole new project to my solution.

Comment: We decided to opt for the registry option in our project, so I didn't look to deep into this MSI wrapper. However,  you could always opt to import the classes in your project directly (thereby putting them in a sub-folder or something) to keep it tidy. This will avoid the need to link a separate project if you don't want that. Another option is building the MSI wrapper and linking the DLL file.

Comment: Good idea, I'm still not sure about creating registry as I'm not sure if the application will have that permission in client device. But that seems like the cleanest solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is partially possible.  You can acquire the appdata local directory on the client system from your service code using:

```
var p = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Then you can add the part that is specific to your application ("xx/yy/zz") as that would not be anywhere in the environment.  I would suggest using:

```
Path.Combine(p, "xx/yy/zz/yourfile.zip");
```

If the special folder above is not the one you need you can refer to the rest of the enumerated values here on msdn for the [SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Problem is I don't know the "xx/yy/zz" bits, that's created on the fly

Comment: Then the answer is no, it isn't possible.  Unless you can recreate the "on the fly" part using the same exact algorithm.  meaning, if it is using company/application/version or some recreatable pattern.